# Rest Client result unreadable in pentaho

Tags: rest, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I have built a transformation that is supposed to fetch info from Snowflake. I generate the token and I am able to query the spaces and I receiving the "readable" output for partition 0. The next step is trying to move on onto the next partition but the response I get is something I am not able to use further. The HTTP code is 200 as expected, but the data is just unusable. This is working fine in Postman.

I tried a lot of parameters and it did not work. This is the result I get.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iiL8.png)

Comment: you get a response with status 200 wich is good, the problem you have here has to do with the response type, try to share your fetch code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We hit this issue too. The problem is that Snowflake returns the data in gzip compressed format and for some reason the Spoon REST Client does not correctly uncompress it (hence the binary gloop).

We tested with Spoon v6 and v9 and in both the REST Client does not interpret it correctly, but in v9 it looks like the HTTP client does handle it correctly (it does not in v6).
Since we currently can't use v9 in production, we found a workaround on v6 where we call curl (with the --compressed option) using the Spoon "Execute a process" or "Shell" (jobs only) steps to do the GET query, output the result to a file and then use the JSON Input step to read from this file.

Let me know if you need more details.